# Present a view controller on top another one without full screen

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I have `MainViewController` and `AddViewController` that should be presented when the user clicks on a button in `MainViewController`.

I've tried to use:

```
self.presentViewController(AddViewController(), animated: false, completion: nil)
```

but it presents it all over the screen (full screen).

I've searched for some answers in StackOverflow but I found a solution just for iPad.

So how can I present the view in the correct way?

Note: I set the `AddViewController`'s view's frame in the `Xib` file.

Comment: init your otherVC, then call `[mainVC.view addSubview:otherVC.view];`

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AddSubview function. Check this code.

Create a class file:

```
class MyClass: UIView {
    class func instanceFromNib() -> UIView {
        return UINib(nibName: "nib file name", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as UIView
    }
}
```

Then you can use this class to grab the view from xib:

```
var myview = MyClass.instanceFromNib()
```

And then you can add this view wherever you want:

```
var presenterStoryBoard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "nameofstoryboard", bundle: nil)
var myview = MyClass.instanceFromNib()

var vc = presenterStoryBoard.instantiateInitialViewController() as MainViewController

publisherViewController.view.addSubview(myview.view)
```